# Access element's id inside jQuery load()

Tags: jquery

I have a few divs that are empty at start and that I want to fill with content dynamically. I'd like to use jQuery for that.
All divs start with the name "foo_" and then an individual identifier, as in "foo_a1". The id is to be used to find the right content for each div.

On my onLoad() function I have declared the following:

```
$("[id^=foo_]").load("folder/"+this.id);
```

Unfortunately, this.id is "undefined" in that scope. The same goes for

```
$(this)[0].id
```

How can I access the elements id inside the load function? I get the feeling it should be really easy but...

Some more info: The jQuery function html() accepts functions as the parameter and:

```
$("[id^=foo_]").html(function(){return this.id;});
```

does fill the divs with their corresponding ids. ( However: html(this.id) doesn't work. this.id is also "undefined" in that case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the set of elements and then inside the each handler use `this.id` to access the target element's id

```
$("[id^=foo_]").each(function(){
    $(this).load("folder/"+this.id;});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. NOTE: I had a syntax error in my original post that got into the answer, it should be: $(this).load("folder/"+this.id);